# MySQL - IF within SELECT

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT id, name, parent_id AS pID, 

(SELECT parent_id
FROM category
WHERE id = pID)
AS grandparent_id, 

(SELECT parent_id
FROM category
WHERE id = grandparent_id) 
AS greatgrandparent_id, 

(SELECT name
FROM category
WHERE id = pID)
AS parent, 

(SELECT name
FROM category
WHERE id = grandparent_id)
AS grandparent, 

(SELECT name
FROM category
WHERE id = greatgrandparent_id)
AS greatgrandparent

FROM category
WHERE active = '1'
HAVING grandparent IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY grandparent_id, parent_id, sort, id ASC
```

When the `greatgrandparent` IS NULL I want it to display the `grandparent` value instead.  Is this possible?

I've tried `CASE WHEN` but must be getting the syntax wrong somewhere as it keeps throwing an error.

Comment: Why don't you do ISNULL(greatgrandparent_id, grandparent_id).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution: `IFNULL(greatgrandparent, grandparent)`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a **having** clause without a **group by** clause.

Answer (score 0):

May be this code helps you.

SELECT id, name, parent_id AS pID, 
case when grandparent IS NOT NULL then
(SELECT parent_id FROM category WHERE id = grandparent_id) 
else
(SELECT parent_id FROM category WHERE id = pID)
end as _parent_id,
case when grandparent IS NOT NULL then 
(SELECT name FROM category WHERE id = grandparent_id) 
else
(SELECT name FROM category WHERE id = pID) 
end AS _parent_name
    FROM category WHERE active = '1'
    ORDER BY grandparent_id, parent_id, sort, id ASC

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite this using left joins with aliases and coalesce. 
Given this

```
/*
CREATE TABLE CATEGORY(ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(20), PARENT_ID INT);
TRUNCATE TABLE CATEGORY;
INSERT INTO CATEGORY VALUES
(1,'AAAA',2),(2,'AAA',3),(3,'AA',4),(4,'A',5),
(10,'BBBB',11),(11,'BBB',12)
;

*/
```

This code

```
SELECT  C.ID,C.NAME,C.PARENT_ID ,
            CP.NAME AS PARENTNAME,CP.PARENT_ID AS PARENT_PARENT_ID,
            CG.NAME AS GRANDPARENTNAME,
            CG.PARENT_ID AS GRANDPARENT_PARENT_ID,
            CGG.NAME AS GREATGRANDPARENTNAME ,
            CGG.PARENT_ID AS GREATGRANDPARENT_PARENT_ID
FROM        CATEGORY C
LEFT JOIN   CATEGORY CP ON CP.ID = C.PARENT_ID
LEFT JOIN   CATEGORY CG ON CG.ID = CP.PARENT_ID
LEFT JOIN   CATEGORY CGG ON CGG.ID = CG.PARENT_ID
ORDER BY C.ID;
```

Results in

```
+------+------+-----------+------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+
| ID   | NAME | PARENT_ID | PARENTNAME | PARENT_PARENT_ID | GRANDPARENTNAME | GRANDPARENT_PARENT_ID | GREATGRANDPARENTNAME | GREATGRANDPARENT_PARENT_ID |
+------+------+-----------+------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+
|    1 | AAAA |         2 | AAA        |                3 | AA              |                     4 | A                    |                          5 |
|    2 | AAA  |         3 | AA         |                4 | A               |                     5 | NULL                 |                       NULL |
|    3 | AA   |         4 | A          |                5 | NULL            |                  NULL | NULL                 |                       NULL |
|    4 | A    |         5 | NULL       |             NULL | NULL            |                  NULL | NULL                 |                       NULL |
|   10 | BBBB |        11 | BBB        |               12 | NULL            |                  NULL | NULL                 |                       NULL |
|   11 | BBB  |        12 | NULL       |             NULL | NULL            |                  NULL | NULL                 |                       NULL |
+------+------+-----------+------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+
```

and this code

```
SELECT  C.ID,C.NAME,C.PARENT_ID ,
            CP.NAME AS PARENTNAME,CP.PARENT_ID AS PARENT_PARENT_ID,
            COALESCE(CG.NAME,CP.NAME) AS GRANDPARENTNAME,
            COALESCE(CG.PARENT_ID,CP.PARENT_ID) AS GRANDPARENT_PARENT_ID,
            COALESCE(CGG.NAME,CG.NAME) AS GREATGRANDPARENTNAME ,
            COALESCE(CGG.PARENT_ID,CG.PARENT_ID) AS GREATGRANDPARENT_PARENT_ID
FROM        CATEGORY C
LEFT JOIN   CATEGORY CP ON CP.ID = C.PARENT_ID
LEFT JOIN   CATEGORY CG ON CG.ID = CP.PARENT_ID
LEFT JOIN   CATEGORY CGG ON CGG.ID = CG.PARENT_ID
ORDER BY C.ID
```

results in

```
+------+------+-----------+------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+
| ID   | NAME | PARENT_ID | PARENTNAME | PARENT_PARENT_ID | GRANDPARENTNAME | GRANDPARENT_PARENT_ID | GREATGRANDPARENTNAME | GREATGRANDPARENT_PARENT_ID |
+------+------+-----------+------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+
|    1 | AAAA |         2 | AAA        |                3 | AA              |                     4 | A                    |                          5 |
|    2 | AAA  |         3 | AA         |                4 | A               |                     5 | A                    |                          5 |
|    3 | AA   |         4 | A          |                5 | A               |                     5 | NULL                 |                       NULL |
|    4 | A    |         5 | NULL       |             NULL | NULL            |                  NULL | NULL                 |                       NULL |
|   10 | BBBB |        11 | BBB        |               12 | BBB             |                    12 | NULL                 |                       NULL |
|   11 | BBB  |        12 | NULL       |             NULL | NULL            |                  NULL | NULL                 |                       NULL |
+------+------+-----------+------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+
```